# How can I pass key word arguments into the function `_extract_celery_task_args(*args: tuple, **kwargs: dict)`?

Tags: python, arguments

So I have the following function which I am trying to unit test:

```
def _extract_celery_task_args(*args: tuple, **kwargs: dict):
    ....
```

I tried something like:

```
def test_extract_celery_task_args_max_four_args(mock_ConvertToParsingIntDate):
    args = ('task', 'parser_code', 'group_name', 'date')
    kwargs = {'mic': 'XEUR', 'something': 'else'}

    try:
        _extract_celery_task_args(args, kwargs)

    except ValueError as ve:
        assert False, ("More than 4 positional arguments passed to _extract_celery_task_args"
                       "function")
```

But when I set a breakpoint inside `_extract_celery_task_args` and print out `args` and `kwargs`, I get:

```
args = (('task', 'parser_code', 'group_name', 'date'), {'mic': 'XEUR', 'something': 'else'})
kwargs = {}
```

Am I passing in `kwargs` wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you are calling `_extract_celery_task_args(args, kwargs)`, which means the `args` variable will be treated as a single argument, and the `kwargs` variable will be treated as an empty dictionary.
  To fix this:

```
_extract_celery_task_args(*args, **kwargs)
```

- By using `*args` and `**kwargs`, individual elements of `args` will be passed as separate positional arguments, and the key-value pairs in `kwargs` will be passed as keyword arguments.

Comment: I don't follow. In my unit test, what do I pass in? Or how do I structure it?

Comment: Ahh okay I kind of got it. If I change the call in my unit test to `_extract_celery_task_args(*args, **kwargs)` as you suggested it works, but when I `print(args)` I unexpectedly get: `args = ('task', 'parser_code', 'group_name', 'date')
kwargs = {'mic': 'XEUR', 'something': 'else'}`

Comment: But `kwargs` is correct now when I print it, it produces: `{'mic': 'XEUR', 'something': 'else'}`

Comment: They are printing correctly as i see the values in your code `*args` and `**kwargs`

Comment: Use `args` and `kwargs` as `tuple` and `dict` resp. , like you do in python and  follow up a tutorial for better understanding.

Comment: I am sorry, i wasn't clear enough why don't you follow this tutorial - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are passing the args and kwargs arguments correctly in your test, but there is an issue with the way you are defining the args parameter in your _extract_celery_task_args function. The *args parameter is used to collect any additional positional arguments as a tuple, and the **kwargs parameter collects keyword arguments as a dictionary. In your test, you are already passing args and kwargs as a tuple and a dictionary, respectively, so there's no need to use the * and ** unpacking operators in the function definition.

You need to remove these * and ** in testing mode, or rewrite your test.

Here's how you can modify your _extract_celery_task_args function definition:

```
def _extract_celery_task_args(args: tuple, kwargs: dict):
    # Your function logic here
```

If you want to keep the *args and **kwargs syntax in your _extract_celery_task_args function, you should adjust your test accordingly. In this case, you need to pass your arguments with the correct unpacking syntax. Here's how you can modify your test to work with the existing function definition:

```
def test_extract_celery_task_args_max_four_args(mock_ConvertToParsingIntDate):
    args = ('task', 'parser_code', 'group_name', 'date')
    kwargs = {'mic': 'XEUR', 'something': 'else'}

    try:
        _extract_celery_task_args(*args, **kwargs)

    except ValueError as ve:
        assert False, ("More than 4 positional arguments passed to _extract_celery_task_args"
                       " function")
```

In this modified test, *args and **kwargs are used to unpack the values from the args tuple and the kwargs dictionary, respectively, when calling _extract_celery_task_args. This way, your function will receive the arguments in the format it expects with the *args and **kwargs parameters, and your test should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks Gordian, this almost solves it, when I use the above and print `args` in my function, I am returned: 

`args = ('task', 'parser_code', 'group_name', 'date') kwargs = {'mic': 'XEUR', 'something': 'else'}`

Comment: What I expect is just `('task', 'parser_code', 'group_name', 'date')`